# Probability book with solutions that covers multivariate normals and different convergence concepts

Tags: probability, book-recommendation

I want to self study some probability, especially different properties of multivariate normal distributions. Also I am interested in studying different convergence concepts. I would be very thankful if you could recommend me some book that covers this topics and has a solution manual.

Comment: Given what you describe, you might be better off with a statistics book I think.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the followings help you:

[https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Random-Variables-Stochastic-Processes/dp/0071226613](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071226613)

[https://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Probability-9th/dp/032179477X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032179477X)

[https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Information-Theory-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471241954) (This book is about information theory but has a rich probability background)

Please let me know if any of the sources were useful

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately these sources were not very useful. I am looking for a book like Allan Gut's intermediate course in probability. In that book there are chapters devoted to convergence concepts and multivariate normals, and exercises are very good, but unfortunately there is no solution manual.